# Are managed pointers in c++/cli initialized to nullptr automatically using GCRoot?

Tags: c++-cli

I need to initialize to a variable only once in C++/CLI class accessible to managed code. Is a managed pointer initialized to `nullptr` when using `gcroot`? Specifically will the `Initialize` function below work as I expect? And only create the `MyOtherClass` once no matter how many times `MyClass::Intialize` is called?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   void Initialize();

private:

#ifdef _MANAGED
    gcroot<MyOtherClass^> _myOtherClass;
#endif
};

void MyClass::Initialize()
{
    if(_myOtherClass == nullptr)
    {
        _myOtherClass = gcnew MyOtherClass();
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. And the managed object accessing this is written in C#. I'm relatively new to CLI code. And I wasn't able to find the answer quickly by Googling it. And I'm sure someone in this community knows the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed handles are default initialized to `nullptr`, per [Default initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/nullptr-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160#example-default-initialization): "*when handles are declared and not explicitly initialized, they are default initialized to nullptr*".

> ```
>   if(_myOtherClass == nullptr)
> ```

The above fails to compile with `error C2088: '==': illegal for struct` because `gcroot` wraps a `GCHandle` structure, which cannot be directly compared against `nullptr`.

To check the *target* handle (not the *wrapper* handle), use the following, which works as expected.

```
  if(static_cast<MyOtherClass^>(_myOtherClass) == nullptr)
```